# Re-form a Pandas Data Frame to a More Concise One

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and have a pandas data frame which is the result of appending a multiple entities. Following is an example of the data frame (It can be bigger than this):

| main_tag | tag | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| geneid | geneid | 121175336 |
| status | status | live |
| create-date | Date-std_year | 2017 |
| create-date | Date-std_month | 4 |
| create-date | Date-std_day | 0 |
| update-date | Date-std_year | 2021 |
| update-date | Date-std_month | 3 |
| update-date | Date-std_day | 21 |
| Org-ref_taxname | Org-ref_taxname | Gmax |
| Org-ref_db | Dbtag_db | taxon1 |
| Org-ref_db | Object-id_id | 3845 |
| OrgName_div | OrgName_div | PLN |
| geneid | geneid | 121175335 |
| status | status | live |
| create-date | Date-std_year | 2011 |
| create-date | Date-std_month | 4 |
| create-date | Date-std_day | 20 |
| update-date | Date-std_year | 2021 |
| update-date | Date-std_month | 4 |
| update-date | Date-std_day | 21 |
| Org-ref_taxname | Org-ref_taxname | Glycine |
| Org-ref_db | Dbtag_db | taxon2 |
| Org-ref_db | Object-id_id | 3847 |
| OrgName_div | OrgName_div | LSA |
| geneid | geneid | 121175334 |
| status | status | live |
| create-date | Date-std_year | 2011 |
| create-date | Date-std_month | 6 |
| create-date | Date-std_day | 20 |
| update-date | Date-std_year | 2018 |
| update-date | Date-std_month | 8 |
| update-date | Date-std_day | 21 |
| Org-ref_taxname | Org-ref_taxname | GlycineMin |
| Org-ref_db | Dbtag_db | taxon3 |
| Org-ref_db | Object-id_id | 38467 |
| OrgName_div | OrgName_div | PLN |

As tables shows, the sub-dataframe from "geneid" to "OrgName_div" is been repeated with different values and I need the fastest way to transpose and change it to something like this:

| geneid | status | create-date | update-date | Org-ref_taxname | Org-ref_db | Org-ref_db | OrgName_div |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 121175336 | live | 2017-4-2 | 2021-3-21 | Gmax | taxon1 | 3845 | PLN |
| 121175335 | live | 2011-4-20 | 2021-4-21 | Glycine | taxon2 | 3847 | LSA |
| 121175334 | live | 2011-6-20 | 2018-8-21 | GlycineMin | taxon3 | 38467 | PLN |

Here is the code that generate this data frame which is basically parsing a huge xml file:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree

class EntrezGene:
    def __init__(self, fh,tg):
        self.context = etree.iterparse(fh, events=("end",),tag=tg,huge_tree=True)

    def _parse(self):
        for event, elem in self.context:
            yield elem
            elem.clear()
            while elem.getprevious() is not None:
                del elem.getparent()[0]

    def sequence(self, elements):
        _elements = {}#[]
        for elem in elements:
            if len(elem):
                _elements[elem.tag]= dict(self.sequence(elem))
            else:
                _elements[elem.tag] =elem.text
        return _elements

    def __iter__(self):
        for xml_EntrezGene in self._parse():
            if len(xml_EntrezGene.attrib):
                EntrezGene = {xml_EntrezGene.tag: xml_EntrezGene.attrib[next(iter(xml_EntrezGene.attrib))]} #xml_EntrezGene.attrib
                mainTag = xml_EntrezGene.tag
            elif len(xml_EntrezGene.text.strip()):#len(xml_EntrezGene.text) :
                EntrezGene = {xml_EntrezGene.tag: xml_EntrezGene.text}
                mainTag = xml_EntrezGene.tag 
            else:
                EntrezGene = {}
                mainTag = xml_EntrezGene.tag
            for elem in xml_EntrezGene:
                # if elem is Sequence
                if len(elem):
                    # Append tuple(tag, value)
                    EntrezGene[elem.tag] = self.sequence(elem)
                    mainTag = elem.getparent().tag
                else:
                    EntrezGene[elem.tag] = elem.text
                    mainTag = elem.getparent().tag

            yield EntrezGene, mainTag

def recursive_items(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if  type(value) is dict: 
            #print(key)
            yield from recursive_items(value)
        else:
            yield (key, value)

poTags =['geneid','status','OrgName_div','Org-ref_db','Org-ref_taxname','create-date', 'update-date']

def extract_xml_inf(xmlFileName, tagNames):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['main_tag','tag', 'value'])
    with open(xmlFileName, 'rb') as in_xml: 
        for record in EntrezGene(in_xml,tg=tagNames):
            for key, value in record[0].items():
                if isinstance(value, (dict)):
                    for subKey, subValue in recursive_items(value):
                        df = df.append({'main_tag': record[1],'tag': subKey,'value': subValue}, ignore_index=True)      
                else:
                    df = df.append({'main_tag': record[1],'tag': key,'value': value}, ignore_index=True)
        #print(df)
    return df
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `df.assign(id = (df.main_tag == 'geneid').cumsum()).groupby(['id', 'main_tag']).aggregate({'value':'-'.join}).unstack()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
df1 = df.assign(id = (df.main_tag == 'geneid').cumsum()).\
    groupby(['id', 'main_tag']).aggregate({'value':'-'.join}).reset_index().\
    pivot('id', 'main_tag', 'value')[df.main_tag.unique()] 

print(df1)

main_tag     geneid status create-date update-date  Org-ref_taxname  Org-ref_db OrgName_div  
id                                                                   
1         121175336   live    2017-4-0   2021-3-21            Gmax  taxon1-3845         PLN   
2         121175335   live   2011-4-20   2021-4-21         Glycine  taxon2-3847         LSA    
3         121175334   live   2011-6-20   2018-8-21      GlycineMin taxon3-38467         PLN
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can go about this differently from the start. If you need to append everything, then reshape, someone else might have a solution for you.

Before concatenating, transpose just the value columns, then concatenate them. Then you can make the modifications to the dates. I don't have your code used to join your data, so you'll have to modify this statement as needed.

```
# hold individual df in a list
df_hold =[]
for i in range(3):
    # .T for transpose
    df_hold.append(df[['value']].T)
df = pd.concat(df_hold)

# note the _c in some of the dates to remove the chance of duplicate column names
tags = ['geneid', 'status', 'Date-std_year_c', 'Date-std_month_c', 'Date-std_day_c', 'Date-std_year', 'Date-std_month',
'Date-std_day', 'Org-ref_taxname', 'Dbtag_db', 'Object-id_id', 'OrgName_div']

df.columns = tags

df['create-date'] = df.apply(lambda x: '-'.join([x['Date-std_year_c'], x['Date-std_month_c'], x['Date-std_day_c']]), axis=1)
df['update-date'] = df.apply(lambda x: '-'.join([x['Date-std_year'], x['Date-std_month'], x['Date-std_day']]), axis=1)

# drop unwanted columns
df = df.drop(['Date-std_year_c', 'Date-std_month_c', 'Date-std_day_c', 'Date-std_year', 'Date-std_month',
'Date-std_day'], axis=1).set_index('geneid', drop=True)
```

this is just running the first geneid three times, that is why the data is the same in each line

```
          status Org-ref_taxname Dbtag_db Object-id_id OrgName_div create-date update-date
geneid
121175336   live            Gmax   taxon1         3845         PLN    2017-4-0   2021-3-21
121175336   live            Gmax   taxon1         3845         PLN    2017-4-0   2021-3-21
121175336   live            Gmax   taxon1         3845         PLN    2017-4-0   2021-3-21
```